# Rest API - when to use which method

Tags: api, rest

I was looking for some Rest API tutorials and specifications for building them. So, i have found one ( http://jsonapi.org/ ) and decided to build one by this specification.

As in many others and in this one as well are quite well explained about response and request formats, however I have missed about endpoints stuctures and some real world examples when to use which method (POST, GET, etc...).

For example there's `/v1/api/users` endpoint which is responsible for querying users and creating them. If understand it correctly for user authentication, and registration i should use create separate endpoints:

- `/v1/api/registration not /v1/api/users/registration`
- `/v1/api/login not /v1/api/users/login`

That's right?

How about methods when i'm requesting my endpoints by which factors i should use which method? For example i have following endpoints:

- `/v1/api/login`
- `/v1/api/activation`

For registration it's clear enought to use PUT, POST because it's CREATE method but but how about these login and activation methods? Because it's none of creation, deletion or updating actions i think i should use GET method, but it's o.k. to send password via GET?

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle login in general is by creating a `/sessions` endpoint, because that's the resource that's being created when you login.

So to login you would call:

```
POST /sessions
     username=john
     password=123456
```

When successful, it would return the session as a JSON object:

```
{ id: 'some_unique_secure_id' }
```

For activation, you could have something similar:

```
POST /activations
     token=secure_token
```

Which, on success, could for example return the user as a JSON object.